# How to join several jar-s into one big jar and remove all duplicated classes automatically?

Tags: java, android, jar

I have an Android Studio project with large ammount of jar libs. But when i am trying to compile it - i am getting **DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK**. This is happening because of some classes are present in multiple jars. How can i join all jars into one and remove duplicated entries? May be with Android Studio or some 3-rd party app? Thanks